# Ordenar por data não funciona - Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, firestore

Olá, tenho uma variável no banco de dados que contém a data em formato "dd/MM/yyyy", quando tento usar o orderBy de uma query com essa data o firebase usa apenas os dias (dd) para ordenar o meu recyclerView, fazendo com que a consulta não seja ordenada de modo eficiente, como eu posso contornar essa problemática? Não tem como remover os "/" depois que eles estão no banco de dados, pois o método .orderBy exige como parametro um valor de campo que está no banco de dados (existente lá (22/04/1947)) e não um valor local, vi que é possível utilizar TimeStamp, mas se eu usar timeStamp, eu mostraria pro meu usuário "144546541", o que não é nada legível...

Exemplo de ordenação: `anuncioRef.orderBy(campo, Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(100);`, onde campo é um valor armazenado no Banco de Dados e que não é alterado aqui, campo aqui é o valor de data (dd/MM/yyyy)

Comment: Você está armazenando sua data no formato de string ou está utilizando o tipo de dados data?

Comment: Não da pra alterar essa string data pra outro formato no banco de dados? exemplo: "yyyyMMdd" ou "yyyy-MM-dd" ficaria -"19470422" ou "1947-04-22". Nesse formato você conseguiria ordernar.

Comment: Armazenando como String, não tem como armazenar como data por causa do //

Comment: O problema é que se eu alterar pra esse formato, na hora de exibir os anuncios eu tenho que adicionar as / / manualmente, né?

Answer (score -1):

Depois de obter a data do banco de dados, eu formatei ela seguindo esse [tutorial](https://www.guj.com.br/t/formatar-string-como-data/39673/3)

e o código ficou assim no RecyclerView meu:

```
 String data = anuncioPrincipal.getDataAnuncio();
        SimpleDateFormat formInicio = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
        SimpleDateFormat formFim = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        try {
            data = formFim.format(formInicio.parse(data));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```